# Do all bodies in a 3-body system orbit their center of mass with respect to each of the other bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, orbital-motion, three-body-problem

### Scenario

Consider an empty universe with just the Earth, Moon and the Sun. The Earth and the Sun will rotate about their center of mass, which is inside the Sun. The Earth and the Moon will orbit their center of mass, which is inside the Earth. The Moon and the Sun will orbit about their center of mass, which is inside the Sun.

### Assumptions

Since the Sun has a center of mass with respect to both the Earth and the Moon, which are moving separately, the Moon pulls on the Sun too, just like the Earth does. This results in the Sun not having a closed loop orbit around their common center of mass. I assume the third body affects the two other bodies in this manner:

- The center of mass of the Earth-Sun system rotates in the same manner the Earth-Moon system rotates about their center of mass
- The center of mass of the Moon-Sun system rotates in the same manner the Earth-Moon system rotates about their center of mass
- These two effects describe the same motion when viewed from different frames (Earth-Sun and Moon-Sun systems)

The above scenario is more pronounced if you consider Jupiter instead of the Moon, but I'm looking at the minute details.

### Question

The question is whether all three bodies always revolve around their common center of mass, which also accounts for the motion of all bodies with respect to one another?

If I'm wrong, how exactly does motion happen in this three body system? (Explain using simple words)

Can this be generalized for an n-body problem? (Although probably not useful for computation but seems good for a mental image)

I think this can be consolidated into a two-body problem by considering the Earth-Moon system as a single body at their center of mass, resulting in a single stationary point as the center of mass of the whole system. That is, I'm taking the center of masses of the Earth-Sun system and the Moon-Sun system, and taking their center of mass, and I expect it to be the center of mass of the Earth-Moon-Sun system.

Or is it just that bodies only revolve around their common center of mass, and the center of mass of the three-body system has no say in describing the motion, aside from being a static point?

### References

1. The motion of the Earth and the Moon around the Sun for a month (from [a WIRED
   article](https://www.wired.com/2012/12/does-the-moon-orbit-the-sun-or-the-earth/))

   [image: Motion of Earth and the Moon around the Sun]
2. The Solar System's barycenter with respect to the Sun (from the
   [Wikipedia article on Barycenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter_(astronomy)))

   [image]

Comment: How accurate answer do you want? There is no general solution to 3-body problem, meaning that getting accurate prediction of trajectories requires numerical calculation, e.g. by simulating them in a computer. When we say "The Earth orbits the Sun", it is an approximation, in which we neglect the influence of any other bodies (e.g. the Moon or other planets).

Comment: I want to know if:
1. If this system has a common stationary (or moving at a constant velocity) center of mass (like two-body problem has)
2. If the bodies can be said to orbit around this point (even though the orbits may be non-repeating)
3. Do all two bodies revolve around their barycenter with respect to each other, ignoring the effects of the third body? (Even though that barycenter itself will be moving relative to the common center of mass; Or that, in this case with just 3 bodies, that barycenter will be orbiting about the common center of mass together with the third body)

Comment: And 4. Considering the Sun's orbit about the common center of mass, it is not likely to be elliptical or repeating since it is influenced by two of the other bodies. I want to know whether this non-repeating motion is intuitive in some way. The common center of mass in this case would be the center of mass of the Moon-Sun system and the Moon-Earth system. Both of them would be moving relative to the stationary common center. Which would also mean that the Sun is wobbling about the common center of mass due to the other two barycenters being pushed around by their respective third bodies.

Comment: Simply put for the last point, the Sun has two circular orbits with respect to either barycenters. Will the orbit around the common center be a sum of the two circular orbits? I'm confused by how the sum of two circular orbits (of varying velocities) will look when combined.